# Can intelligent species evolve to consume and emit ionizing radiation?

Tags: creature-design, radioactivity

Is it possible to have a multi-cellular complex organism capable of emitting ionizing radiation and I am not talking about banana I meant intelligent lifeforms that can develop tools also on top of that these species must consume radioactive substances in large quantity without suffering from any side effects and I am not talking about gorilla... and what kind of traits should my species have so that they cannot be harmed by their craving for exotic foods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radioactive isotopes generally have the same chemistry as the non-radioactive ones, so all the usual biological processes should be able to work in a world where only radioactive isotopes are available, at least briefly.

To be able to survive with all that internal radiation, start with deinococcus radiodurans — it's only a bacterium, but it has the ability to repair its DNA. That same mechanism could probably work in the cells of a larger creature. You'd also want a fairly fast metabolism to deal with things like replacing all the iron in the blood faster than it turns into cobalt.

So far, this is just a creature that can survive a high radiation environment, but it could easily evolve to depend on the radiation - for example it might require a highly efficient cooling system to handle the heat of radioactive decay, but the same system would cause hypothermia if that heat source was no longer available.

Comment: There were some species of fungus detected in the Chernobyl area that thrived on beta radiation.